# Vite PWA-Plugin manifest.webmanifest not visible in directory/vscode but from browser: http://localhost:5173/manifest.webmanifest how to make visible?

Tags: vue.js, vite-plugin-pwa

Vite PWA-Plugin manifest.webmanifest is not visible in file explorer, vscode or terminal but somehow browser can find it : http://localhost:5173/manifest.webmanifest how to make visible?

[image]

[image]

[image]

No luck for file explorer either. I have ability to see hidden files.

I want to know a way that I can edit the manifest.webmanifest.

I tried manually creating file under same name and changing something, but it doesn't overwrite the manifest.webmanifest that's visible from url. I expected it would overwrite it.